# Field form size/format changed

Tags: column, form

After few data/form changes our sharepoint form has changed its format from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I already checked these settings and everything looks ok

**Settings / Advanced Settings / Dialogs -> NO**

**Settings / Form Settings -> Use the default Sharepoint form**

Any others suggestion to fix this?

Comment: Did you use [Configure the list form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration) JSON to format the list form? If yes, please remove the JSON & it should work as 1st image.

Comment: No custom JSON list